# How to "explode" a list inside a function call argument list?

Tags: output-formatting, functional-style

I'm trying to do something like below, but it doesn't work, since `StringForm` requires each item from `parts` to be given individually, and not in a list:

```
parts = ToString /@ {1, 2, 3};
(* this should be StringForm["`` `` ``", 1, 2, 3] and 
   not StringForm["`` `` ``", {1, 2, 3}] *)
StringForm["`` `` ``", parts]
```

I think this could be done with `Flatten` and `Apply`, but can I avoid using `Apply`? (looks ugly)

Comment: How about: `parts = Sequence @@ ToString /@ {1, 2, 3}`

Comment: @RunnyKine Yep, that was exactly what I was looking for. I read about `Sequence` and tried using it, but I missed the `@@` part

Comment: @RunnyKine I notice you used @@ which is shorthand for Apply, which the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think OP meant `Apply[f, expr]` form.

Comment: @kuba In that case, `StringForm["`` `` ``", ##]& @@ parts` would be better IMHO. No need for `Sequence`. -- Oh, forget it, I just saw you already did that.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I agree, well OP accepted an answer with Apply even though was asking to avoid it so it's hard to be sure what it is about :) (*my guess was that he want to avoid explicitly written `Apply`*)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid to explicitly write `Apply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
 parts = Sequence @@ ToString /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

For `StringForm` you don't have to use `ToString` on arguments.

One way to avoid `Apply`, which was introduced to me by rm-rf, was to use `Operate`:

```
parts = {1, 2, 3};
StringForm["`` `` ``", Operate[Sequence &, parts]]
```

> ```
> 1 2 3
> ```

Also, if you want to use `Apply` in slightly different way than RunnyKine:

```
parts = {1, 2, 3};

StringForm["`` `` ``", ##] & @@ parts
```

> ```
> 1 2 3
> ```